# Why does the EMAIL replaces ORG and TITLE in iOS Contacts when VCF File is scanned via QR Code?

Tags: ios, qr-code, vcf-vcard

i try to generate QR Codes as digital vCards - you scan the QR Code and directly add the contact to your contacts on the smartphone.
Therefor I just take the code of a .vcf file and make a QR Code out of it. .vcf file looks like this and in general it works fine:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//macOS 11.6.1//EN
N:Lastname;Name;;;
FN:Name Lastname;
ORG:Company Name;
TITLE:Fancy Title here;
TEL;type=WORK;type=VOICE;type=pref:+49 (0)40 123 456 789
TEL;type=CELL;type=VOICE:+49 (0)174 123 456 78
TEL;type=MAIN:+49 (0) 40 123 456 70
ADR;type=WORK;type=pref:;;Streetname 10;City;;123456;Country
item1.URL;type=pref:www.company.com
item1.X-ABLabel:Website
END:VCARD
```

This is the result after scanning with iPhone (iOS 15.5):
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6x0l.png)

The Company name and the job title are right under the name at the top, which is fine.

BUT as soon i add an email adress to it, the title and company name get replaced by the email.

Code with email here:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//macOS 11.6.1//EN
N:Lastname;Name;;;
FN:Name Lastname;
ORG:Company Name;
TITLE:Fancy Title here;
TEL;type=WORK;type=VOICE;type=pref:+49 (0)40 123 456 789
TEL;type=CELL;type=VOICE:+49 (0)174 123 456 78
TEL;type=MAIN:+49 (0) 40 123 456 70
ADR;type=WORK;type=pref:;;Streetname 10;City;;123456;Country
EMAIL;type=INTERNET:name.lastname@company.com
item1.URL;type=pref:www.company.com
item1.X-ABLabel:Website
END:VCARD
```

New Scan result here:
[Screenshot with email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1JGt.png)

**Does anyone know how i can include the email but keep the company and job title in the contacts on QR Code scan???**

I'm not able to figure out what the reason here is... Camera app bug? QR Code specialty?? iOS Contacts configuration???

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Found the solution yet ?

Comment: No solution yet.. but i found out that it works fine on an iPhone 7 with iOS 15.5. So still no idea but perhaps i'll just wait for iOS 16 to change something?!

Comment: I had the same problem, Do you found the solution for IOS 16 @ennbeh ??

Comment: @ITN the answer from florieger was correct - the company name is not shown right after the scan, but once the contact was saved the company name is in it as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in iOS. Once you add the contact to your address book, the `Company Name` will show up.

It is already visible on the creation screen, after selecting "Create new contact" and the bottom the vCard sheet.